# React - Debounce + useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have created a debounced method **inside** my react component.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const lazyLog = useCallback(
  _.debounce(() => { console.log(count) }, 5000),
  [count]
);
```

and I am calling it inside a useEffect, every time `count` is updated:

```
useEffect(() => {
  lazyLog();
}, [count])
```

The problem I am experiencing is that, as the lazyLog method is recreated on each render, the `debounce` functionality is not applied correctly.

You can check this [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/1Fkgm9INF) to test the code.

How can I fix the code? As the useCallback must include the dependency... I don't find any easy way to handle this... any ideas?

Comment: https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/

Comment: So, in order to use it, instead of debouncing my callback, I have to debounce the effect's dependency right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is stale as it's not included in the dependency array of `useCallback`. Now if you add that the `deBounce` will not work.

Solution is to use a `ref` & hold a copy of the state in that. Then use that in the `debounce`. ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-joliot-srdxxg?file=/src/App.js:376-588))

Also - `[count]` should be `[]` in `useCallback`.

```
const refValue = useRef(count);

const lazyLog = useCallback(
    _.debounce(() => {
      console.log("debounce", refValue.current);
    }, 2000),
    [] // empty
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    refValue.current = count;
    lazyLog();
  }, [count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the `useDebounce` hook, described in the comments, at all, because I want to debounce the callback and not the value.

I think that, in order to avoid problem with the stale state, I will pass the counter as argument, instead of consuming it directly from my state.

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const lazyLog = useCallback(
    _.debounce((count) => { console.log(count); }, 5000),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    lazyLog(count);
  }, [count])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text onPress={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>
        Increase
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

https://snack.expo.dev/67W9HnsRD

Not as clean as it could be but works fine with some minimal changes.